# How can I correctly type the return value from a Postgres database in TypeORM with NestJS?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

## How to correctly type the value returned from the postgres database

Can anyone please explane this moment. I'm new at postgresql, nest and typeorm, and i want to create primitive CRUD application. I have a question about typing at typeorm.

My User Entity:

```
@Entity('user')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  name: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  password: string;

  @Column({
    nullable: true,
    type: 'varchar',
    default: () => 'NULL',
  })
  refreshToken: string;
}
```

My UserService:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
    private usersRepository: Repository<UserEntity>,
  ) {}

  createUser(createUserDto: SignUpDto) {
    return this.usersRepository.save(createUserDto);
  }

  findAllUsers() {
    return this.usersRepository.find({
      select: ['id', 'email', 'name'],
    });
  }

  findUserById(id: number) {
    return this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .select([
        'user.id',
        'user.email',
        'user.name',
      ])
      .where('user.id= :userId', { userId: id })
      .getOne();
  }

  findUserByEmail(email: string) {
    return this.usersRepository.findOneBy({ email });
  }
}
```

**`FindUserById`** is external method (there is a controller method that calls it) . It returns a user with incomplete data without password and refreshToken fields ( I don't think they should be exposed).
**`FindUserByEmail`** is an internal method that is used by another service (`authService`). It returns the complete user data.

The problem is that the inferred return type is `Promise<UserEntity>` in both cases, and I don't see how that could fit both functions.

First, I think the inferred type should be at least `Promise<UserEntity | null>`. But it's not.

Second, I thought TypeORM would automatically infer the data type. The question is, can TypeORM actually do this? And if not, how do I correctly type return values then? Create multiple different data types? Use `Omit`? Type `UserEntity` by adding optional fields? I don't understand.

Comment: Looks like you're rolling your own authentication. It's easy to mess up and create security vulnerabilities. It's better to use an existing battle-tested solution. If you want to learn more, see: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: I also wrote a Medium article about authentication in NodeJS: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-do-authentication-in-nodejs-48c16748749b

Comment: I tried to implement primitive authorization myself to understand the mechanism. Thanks a lot for the materials!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the inferred return type is `Promise<UserEntity>` in both cases, and I don't see how that could fit both functions.
> First, I think the inferred type should be at least `Promise<UserEntity | null>`. But it's not.

You're correct. The options are either it finds it in the db and resolves with `UserEntity`, or it doesn't find it and resolves with `null`.

`UserEntity` is an object. Any object can be `null`. Therefore `UserEntity | null` is the same as just `UserEntity`.

> Second, I thought TypeORM would automatically infer the data type. The question is, can TypeORM actually do this? And if not, how do I correctly type return values then? Create multiple different data types? Use Omit? Type UserEntity by adding optional fields? I don't understand.

TypeORM infers the return type with the assumption that you return the full entity (don't do any `select`s). Since you know more than TypeORM when writing your `UsersService`, you're responsible for specifying more precise type information if you want to. `Partial`/`Omit`/`Pick` are good options for this.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i got the point.
But what do you mean saying "UserEntity is an object. Any object can be null. Therefore UserEntity | null is the same as just UserEntity."
I thought there is a clear distinction between Object type and Null type in typesctript. Why is UserEntity | null the same as UserEntity"?

Comment: @Nik `null` can be assigned to any object type. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#subtype-vs-assignment
Unless you specifically use `strictNullChecks: true`